# A question in linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space and $T:V \to V$ be a linear transformation. Prove there exists a linear transformation $S:V \to V$ such that $TST=T$

I feel this should not be a hard question, but I have some problem with it. $TST=T$ means that $TS=I$ am I right? But not all linear transformations(matrices) are invertible, so then I think $TS=I$ may be wrong, but I don't know what to do next. Could somebody help me? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If $T$ were invertible, then you would just take $S=T^{-1}$ (and that would be your only choice). When $T$ is not invertible, try to construct $S$ as an "inverse" on the range of $T$.

**Edit:** To construct $S$, let $K$ be the kernel of $T$. Expand a basis of $K$ to a basis of $V$, and that way you can construct a complement $L$ of $K$, i.e. $V=K\oplus L$. Then you note that $T$ is injective on $L$. Now you have that $T$, as a map $L\to\text{ran}\, T$ is bijective, so it has an inverse $S':\text{ran}\,T\to L$. Finally, extend $S'$ to a map $S:V\to V$.

Comment: but how to prove that?

Comment: See the edit. ${ }$

Answer (score 1):

Such $S$ is known to be the pseudo-inverse matrix. Let's define the singular value decomposition of $T$ as $T=ABC^*$ where $A$ is an $m-by-m$ unitary matrix over $K$.
$B$ is an $m-by-n$ matrix over $K$ with nonnegative numbers on the diagonal and zeros off the diagonal.
$C$ is an $n-by-n$ unitary matrix over $K$. And define $S=CB^-A^*$ where $B^-$ is the pseudo- inverse of $B$. So, $TST=ABC^*CB^-A^*ABC^*=ABB^-BC^*=ABC^*=T$.